# Have a group of objects next to each other in HTML be centered

Tags: css, html

I'm making a custom homepage where there are multiple lists of links next to each other. I don't, however, know how to have them all be centered while still retaining the format I want. This is what the homepage looks like:[image: what the homepage looks like]

How do I make it so that the lists of links are centered together in the middle of the page, but still formatted to be next to each other like in the picture? Here's a pastebin of my index.html file: http://pastebin.com/wW1GzUUJ and one of my style.css file: http://pastebin.com/BsHd42ED for reference.

Comment: Use jsfiddle.net to create a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `display` of `inline-block` for your `.all` elements. Then apply a `vertical-align` of `top` so that the titles appear at the top. I gave your group titles a class of `title` to simplify the CSS a bit.

Here's a dynamic version that I created in JSFiddle. You can add or remove links from groups or create new ones on-the-fly with a JSON object.

> https://jsfiddle.net/44b5oj4z/1/

```css
body {
  background-color: #282828;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  color: #ebdbb2;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ebdbb2;
  font-size: 90;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

list {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.all {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.all:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 12em;
}

.google {
  background-color: #cc241d;
}

.reddit {
  background-color: #458588;
}

.programming {
  background-color: #689d6a;
}

.gaming {
  background-color: #d65d0e;
}

.linux {
  background-color: #98971a;
}

.links {
  text-align: center;
  color: #282828;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ebdbb2;
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="all">
  <div class="title google"><h3>google</h3></div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><p>google</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions"><p>youtube</p></a>
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive"><p>drive</p></a>
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"><p>gmail</p></a>
    <a href="https://play.google.com/books"><p>books</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="all">
  <div class="title reddit"><h3>reddit</h3></div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/"><p>front</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/"><p>/r/linux</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/"><p>/r/unixporn</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/"><p>/r/chemistry</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="all">
  <div class="title programming"><h3>programming</h3></div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="https://github.com/"><p>github</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.codecademy.com/learn"><p>codecademy</p></a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><p>stack overflow</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="all">
  <div class="title gaming"><h3>gaming</h3></div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/"><p>steam</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.gog.com/"><p>gog</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="all">
  <div class="title linux"><h3>linux</h3></div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/"><p>archwiki</p></a>
    <a href="https://aur.archlinux.org/"><p>aur</p></a>
    <a href="https://forum.antergos.com/"><p>antergos</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use flex box.

Contain all of your .all divs in a parent container, have display: flex on it.

That is all you need. Here is what you could do.

```css
body {
  background-color: #282828;
}
h3 {
  color: #ebdbb2;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ebdbb2;
  font-size: 90;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
list {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.links {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}
.google {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cc241d;
  width: 200px;
}
.reddit {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #458588;
  width: 200px;
}
.programming {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #689d6a;
  width: 200px;
}
.gaming {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d65d0e;
  width: 200px;
}
.linux {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #98971a;
  width: 200px;
}
.links {
  text-align: center;
  color: #282828;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ebdbb2;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="all">
    <div class="google">
      <h3>google</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <p>google</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions">
        <p>youtube</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive">
        <p>drive</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox">
        <p>gmail</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://play.google.com/books">
        <p>books</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="reddit">
      <h3>reddit</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">
        <p>front</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/">
        <p>/r/linux</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/">
        <p>/r/unixporn</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/">
        <p>/r/chemistry</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="programming">
      <h3>programming</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://github.com/">
        <p>github</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.codecademy.com/learn">
        <p>codecademy</p>
      </a>
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
        <p>stack overflow</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="gaming">
      <h3>gaming</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/">
        <p>steam</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.gog.com/">
        <p>gog</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="linux">
      <h3>linux</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/">
        <p>archwiki</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://aur.archlinux.org/">
        <p>aur</p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://forum.antergos.com/">
        <p>antergos</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```